# Wordpress error : Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The whole error:

Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /www/.../wp-content/themes/.../includes/meta.page.php on line 178

```
'desc' => esc_html__('Default value on Theme Options: ', 'consultaid') . 
((isset(Themeton_Std::getopt('social_sharevisibility')[$post_type.'s']) && 
Themeton_Std::getopt('social_sharevisibility')[$post_type.'s'] == '0') ? 
esc_attr__('Hidden', 'consultaid') : esc_attr__('Show', 'consultaid')),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try taking the call to the static class out of the `isset` check. Set a variable then use that in the isset() function.

```
$var = Themeton_Std::getopt('social_sharevisibility')[$post_type.'s'];

'desc' => esc_html__('Default value on Theme Options: ', 'consultaid') . 
((isset($var) && Themeton_Std::getopt('social_sharevisibility')[$post_type.'s'] == '0') ? 
 esc_attr__('Hidden', 'consultaid') : esc_attr__('Show', 'consultaid')),
```

Comment: Do you think this error is happening because the PHP version in the server is PHP 5.2.6?

Comment: In my experience I have gotten that error when PHP does not support running a certain function inside of another function.  Since that is a ternary operation it makes it a little hard to follow.  Can you show us the whole function?

Comment: The PHP version on the server was 5.2.6,and I think the theme(Wordpress theme) wasn't supporting earlier versions